# How make a screen with fields in VSCode Plugin

Tags: user-interface, plugins, visual-studio-code

How do I create a custom screen, with text fields and dropdowns for a plugin in VSCode, something like the settings screens I saw in some plugins, or like this Jira screen which is a form for adding a new issue?

[image: sample jira new issue]

Comment: Create a Webview panel and you have all the HTML/CSS/JavaScript to be used. The current theme colors are injected and can be used in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

That example is using the VS Code [webview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). Webviews let you render arbitrary html in the editor, so you can create as complex a form as you wish. [This example extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-sample) shows how to use the webview api.

For simple input cases however please try using VS Code's native input APIs, such as [QuickInput](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/quickinput-sample)